# How can ford fulkerson be explained concisely?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

After going through the resource list, is the following a way to explain ford fulkerson concisely ?

Graphs is represent is a 2D matrix with flow capacity as a tuple in each cell.

```
while exists (P_residual = residual graph path from S to T obtained via BFS )
    modify actual and residual graph with P_residual by
    1. getting capacity of P_residual.Its the min of all edges in the path P_residual
    2. transfer this capacity from P_residual in residual graph to actual graph. This would mean subtracting from residual graph matrix and adding to actual graph matrix
```

I am assuming *P_residual* is the *augmented path* ?

### Resources

- [CMU Lec 1](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eavrim/451f11/lectures/lect1025.pdf)
- [CMU Lec 2](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eavrim/451f11/lectures/lect1027.pdf)
- [ST1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534278/residual-graph-max-flow-intuition-and-correctness)
- [ST2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049078/whats-the-intuition-behind-augmenting-paths-in-residual-graphs-ford-fulkerson)

Answer (score 1):

The title and the body of your question ask different questions.

Ford-Fulkerson cannot be explained more concisely than giving the algorithm, which in turn means you should explain the residual graph.

The pseudo-code snippet you have attached is not very satisfactory.  It's certainly concise, but it leaves a lot of necessary details out.  For example, you need to at least say that you pick the minimum residual capacity of the path as the value you augment with, and you need also to say how you modify the graph(s?).

You say "modify actual and residual graph", but I don't think that's correct.  You either modify the *flow*, and then reconstruct the residual graph, or you modify the residual graph.  You probably don't modify the actual graph.

Comment: I have made some modifications. Can you further modify the pseudo code in my question OR better yet in your answer with clear defintions. Reason is websites are quite long and confusing and take away the bigger picture. So a shorter answer might help.

Comment: If you search the internet for "ford fulkerson pseudocode" you literally get a what you ask for as the first hit.  It has a nice 12 line pseudocode description of FF.  I don't think you get much better than that.